# How to Run cssnano from Command Line

Tags: css, node.js, jar, cmd, yui

I'm not completely familiar with node JS, but I see that cssnano is a JS tool to minify CSS that completes this task in a more advanced way than the deprecate YUI compressor. Only problem is, that I can't figure out how exactly to run this tool on a single file like I can with the YUI compressor.

I'm used to running that command like this

```
java -jar compilers\yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar --type=css --line-break=2048  infile.css -o "outfile.css"
```

Which is nice and easy since I use a tool I wrote to loop through all of my CSS files and do this to each one, but I can't figure out at all how to use cssnano in place of YUI to do the same task.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally figured it out.

Had to create a .js file somewhere that contained this

```
var cssnano = require('cssnano');
var fs = require('fs');


cssnano.process(fs.readFileSync(process.argv[2])).then(function (result) {
  fs.writeFileSync(process.argv[3], result);
});
```

And then run it from the command line like

```
node compilers\minifycorec.js infile.css "outfile.css"
```

Comment: Hi Brian, there's no need for this script. The CLI for cssnano is in a separate module, cssnano-cli. So you can `npm install cssnano-cli` and then `cssnano infile.css outfile.css`. Docs are here - https://github.com/ben-eb/cssnano-cli

Comment: That gives the command prompt message about `cssnano` isn't in my path

Comment: @Ben working completely with the `--global` flag, as in `npm install cssnano-cli --global`

Comment: Awesome! Glad to be of help.